# Direction Arrow over my popup

Tags: html, css, wordpress, posts

do you know, why does the direction arrow from my posts slider show over my pop up advert at this website?

http://skkelti.cz/

[image]

Comment: Its coming from bx-wrapper you can always edit that from CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two anchor tags for the arrows has an z-index value 999, which is greater than the popups. Either you increase the popups z-index or reduce the arrows z-index.

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  outline: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 9999;   //Need to change
}
```